# align submenu of a dropdown menu horizontal

Tags: css

i am unable to align my submenus from vertical to horizontal

here is my css code of drop down menu.

i have tried floating left and postition variations 
but it doesn't worked.

Do reply quick as soon as possible.

```
.ddsmoothmenu{
margin-top: 20px;

}

.ddsmoothmenu ul{
z-index:100;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

list-style-type: none;
     }

   /*Top level list items*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
vertical-align: inherit;

   }

 /*Top level menu link items style*/
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li a {
display: block;
height: 23px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 5px;
line-height: 23px;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #a9a2a2;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 400;
outline: none;

  }

    * html .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to behave       correctly*/
   display: inline-block;
  }

 .ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover { /*CSS class that's    dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
     color: #f00;
     background: url(../images/templatemo_menu_hover.png)
 }

/*1st sub level menu*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul {
position: absolute;
width: 160px;
margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
left: 0;
display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/
visibility: hidden;
background: url(../images/templatemo_smm.png) repeat-y
 }

 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul span.top { position: absolute; width: 160px; height: 5px; top: -5px; left: 0;  background: url(../images/templatemo_smt.png) no-repeat; }
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul span.bottom { position: absolute; width: 160px; height: 5px; bottom: -5px; left: 0;  background: url(../images/templatemo_smb.png) no-repeat; }

 /*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
  .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
display: list-item;
float: none;
}

 /*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul{
 top: 0;
 }

 /* Sub level menu links style */
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a{
font-weight: 500;
width: 140px; /*width of sub menus*/
height: 28px;
line-height: 28px;
margin: 0 10px;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: left;
background: none;
color: #a9a2a2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #151515
  }

 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li .last {
border-bottom: none;
 }

 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a.selected, .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a:hover {
color: #f00;
width: 129px;
margin-left: 11px;
background: none;
 }

  /* Holly Hack for IE \*/
 * html .ddsmoothmenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/


  /* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */

 .downarrowclass{
 position: absolute;
 top: 12px;
  right: 7px;
  }

 .rightarrowclass{
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 5px;
   }

 /* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */

.ddshadow{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 }

.toplevelshadow{ /*shadow opacity. Doesn't work in IE*/
 opacity: 0.5;
  }
  /* menu */
```

Comment: You HTML or a jsFiddle will help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
display:inline;
```